# when I need to use SSL private key while making SSL call

Tags: ssl, curl, https, wget

Sorry if this sounds like dump question, I have been reading lot of posts and documents about SSL handshake and how SSL works. I am confused about one thing, it would be great if someone could clarify me.

I know private keys are to be kept secret. But I have seen some GET/POST calls being made (using curl or wget) by specifying private key also in the request, 
for eg if my server DNS is example.com and I am making a SSL call using wget:

```
wget --ca-cert=/etc/certs/ca.crt --certificate=/etc/certs/cert.crt --private-key=/etc/cert/private/privatekey.key --header="Content-Type: application/json" --post-data='{"key":"val"}' https://example.com/test
```

But when we open a SSL web page through browser(say, opening gmail through chrome) we never have to use the private key or rather browser is not aware of the private key. During the handshake browser gets the server public cert & CA then it encrypts the random number to send back to sever to open SSL session.

I know I am missing something silly and getting confused. Can someone tell me when would someone have to use a private key in the SSL request ?

Answer (score 1):

It is used when you want [Mutual Authentication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_authentication). As well as the standard server authentication which requires service providers to pay for certificates etc, and avoid MITM attacks.

Client authentication proves the identity of the client to the server. However this places a burden on users that is usually not justified, and is satisfied by username/password or oauth tokens for clients etc.

It is possible for Client authentication to be optional and fallback to other methods.

Comment: So does this mean if i comment the line ssl_verify_client on(in nginx or something similar in apache2) or make it ssl_verify_client off, I would no longer have to use key while making the above ssl call using wget?

Comment: Yes, although your question isn't clear whether things just work in browsers for the same endpoint.  If that is the case you can probably just run 

`wget --header="Content-Type: application/json" --post-data='{"key":"val"}' https://example.com/test`

But if you are testing an endpoint that *does* enforce client auth, then the changes you suggest would be appropriate.